# Import and export Excel in visual studio 2019. WPF (NET Core) and MVVM

Tags: wpf, export-to-excel, import-from-excel, windows-template-studio, wpf-core

I am totally newbie and trying to make an application that can handle an Excel spreadsheet. I am making it in Visual Studio 2019. It is a WPF application (.NET Core) using MVVM model (I used a template from Windows Template Studio). The idea is to be able to read or import the file .xls, .xlsx, .ods, .cvs, etc. and display it in a DataGridView, create or edit items, and rewrite or export it to the spreadsheet.
I installed different nuget packages. OleDB, compatibility, others that I do not remember. Finally, I deleted the project and started again. Now I posted it on GitHub. I currently have the nuget package System.Data.OleDb and Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility installed. I followed a tutorial but I had to correct many compatibility errors with net framework and windows form.
https://github.com/Lestradez/WPF_NET_CORE_EXCEL

The specific question would be what is the most correct way to implement this functionality or what is the way to correct compatibility errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add in the code you wrote so far

Comment: https://github.com/Lestradez/WPF_NET_CORE_EXCEL

Comment: @LZDEV What is the question? How to solve the compatibility errors?

Comment: Consider editing your question to describe the current problem that you are trying to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, questions and suggestions, I will re-edit the question.